# Wordpress does not create directories?

Tags: wordpress, www

First I will just tell you how my wordpress hierarchy looks like:

`/var/www` has all of the wordpress files, which is different from how it is normally set up as `/var/www/wordpress` (symlinked to `/usr/share/wordpress`). So **`var/www` contains all of the files that `/usr/share/wordpress` would have**, and `/usr/share/wordpress` is symlinked to `/var/www`, with an extra `/var/www/wordpress` symlinked to `/var/www` to prevent possible compatibility issues.

When uploading a file like a favicon or a .zip-ped theme, everything works fine, and when checking if the theme/favicon is uploaded, wordpress shows that it is, and points to a directory that it thinks that it had created, like `http:/localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/...`, which it had not, because the **`uploads` folder is empty!**

And so there is a *broken link* on the internet and the theme is displayed but it has just plain text (because it had reverted to a plain theme I think)

Please help! I am sorry for such a long post but this is really quite a troublesome problem.

I have `chown`ed `/var/www` and `/usr/share/wordpress` to `www-data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - Install using the lates.tar.gz package straight from wordpress, rather than the apt-get ubuntu packaged one.

It is probrably due to incorrect permissions.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Nk3770S4jk&noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to tell Wordpress where to find its own directory. Check under Settings > General for "WordPress Address" and "Site Address".

Make sure the WordPress Address matches the domain name you are using to represent your `www` folder; localhost in this case, or your domain name if you put your server online.

Th other possibility is that you haven't given WordPress execute permissions on your `/var/www` folder. Check the owner of `www`, and make sure you allow WordPress to create files and folders.

Comment: like `chmod 777 /var/www` and `chown -R wordpress /var/www`?